# How to put object inside array in JOLT

Tags: json, mapping, transformation, jolt

How to I put an object in an array. I have an object called "item". I want that entire object in an array.

Left side is the current output. Right side is the desired output.
[image]

What changes do I need to make in JOLT spec to get the desired output?

Input is to long so I have uploaded the input and the jolt spec in Google Drive.

Below is the link- https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1vvdFBPwaHRVvjttUTQP0jzQlqYlGfjFZ?usp=share_link

Comment: Is this question solved?

Comment: Hey, this is resolved. I am really struggling with the other one. Can you please help me with that. I will put the solution after some time.

Comment: Don't worry, Just ask your question and wait for other people to answer you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```json
{
  "operation": "shift",
  "spec": {
    "*": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&2.&1.&[#2]"
      }
    }
  }
}
```